# WPF ViewModels and Bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am designing a WPF Application and have the following ViewModels:

- ProjectViewModel (contains an ObservableCollection of GroupViewModels)
- GroupViewModel   (contains an ObservableCollection of ItemViewModels)
- ItemViewModel

I was planning on representing this with a `Window` that contains multiple `Tabs` that contain `Items`.

Here's how it will look:

[image]

In my `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:ProjectViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

I was planning on binding ViewModel to View UIElements as follows:

- ProjectViewModel -> (bound to) Window
- GroupViewModel -> (bound to) TabItem
- ItemViewModel -> (bound to) some custom control, just shown as a colored rectangle for now

**Here's the problem I can't figure out ...**

The Tabs need to be dynamic (can be added/deleted by the user).

In order to accomplish this, I followed a tutorial on CodeProject.com: [Add/Remove Tabs Dynamically in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493538/Add-Remove-Tabs-Dynamically-in-WPF).

In this code, `TabControl.DataContext` is set to a List of TabItems that has items added/removed based on user actions.

However, if I bind TabControl.DataContext to a List of TabItems, won't I lose the ability to bind it to my GroupViewModel?

Is there a way to bind it to both?

Following MVVM pattern, isn't a UIElement's DataContext supposed to be bound to a ViewModel, not to another UIElement.

Is there a way I can bind my ViewModels to my View UIElements as I had planned and still do the dynamic tabs?

Thank you very much for any ideas or suggestions.

Philip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary to bound each nested collection to the nested element of visual tree. The `DataContext` dependency property inherits through that tree.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:ProjectViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<TabControl
        ItemsSource="{Binding GroupViewModels}">
....
```

Comment: In order for me to use this code, would I need to make my `GroupViewModel` extend `System.Windows.Controls.TabItem`?  Doesn't the Items of a `TabControl` need to be a `TabItem`?